# how to push a new array to json bracket angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, push, frontend

do you guys know how to push a to a json bracket if the json format like this ?

**JSON FORMAT WHEN I PRINT**

```
{  
   "19":[  
      {  
         "group_option_id":"19",
         "variant_id":"417000019",
         "option_value":"Blue",
         "variant_name":"M",
         "sku_code_per_item":"sk-blue-100",
         "prod_weight":"10",
         "prod_stock":"10"
      }
   ],
   "21":[  
      {  
         "group_option_id":"21",
         "variant_id":"417000024",
         "option_value":"Blue",
         "variant_name":"S",
         "sku_code_per_item":"sk-blue-100",
         "prod_weight":"100",
         "prod_stock":"100"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Below is my angular file**

```
        app.controller('edit_product_stock', function($scope,$http){



      $scope.product_id = function(prod_id) 
      {
        $scope.product_id = prod_id;
       $scope.get_stock = [];




         $http.get('get_variant_dtl_data?prod_id='+$scope.product_id+'').then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
               $scope.get_stock = data.data;
            });

      };

     $scope.addNewChoice = function() 
      {

        $scope.get_stock.push({}); // what should i do to add new value in $scope.get_stock
      };

   });
```

**Button to add new value html**

```
  <button ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add new group variant</button>
```

**i got this error when im execute / running the website using this script**

```
$scope.get_stock.push is not a function
```

so that is my code so my plan is when im click the "add new group variant" button angular will be automatically create a new json value in $scope.get_stock

please help, thank you for your time

Comment: declare `$scope.get_stock = [];` above  $scope.product_id within the controller

Comment: i already try but still got a same error, do you have any suggestion ? @Amitd

Answer (score 0):

You can't push things into an object. Your JSON is not an array.
This would be an array:

```
[  
   {
       "19":[  
          {  
             "group_option_id":"19",
             "variant_id":"417000019",
             "option_value":"Blue",
             "variant_name":"M",
             "sku_code_per_item":"sk-blue-100",
             "prod_weight":"10",
             "prod_stock":"10"
          }
       ]
   },
   {
       "21":[  
          {  
             "group_option_id":"21",
             "variant_id":"417000024",
             "option_value":"Blue",
             "variant_name":"S",
             "sku_code_per_item":"sk-blue-100",
             "prod_weight":"100",
             "prod_stock":"100"
          }
       ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answear, but the purpose is i want to make a multidimensional JSON where every variant has a many  information, how to make that happen pelase help ? this json i got in form multidimensional php and i use json_encode to make that format @pelipev

Comment: I just edited my answer. Is that what you are expecting? @denindraresky